# Why the name convention of Laravel relationships so weird?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables:

- users

  - columns: id, name
- books

  - columns: id, name
- book_user:

  - columns: user_id, book_id, state(`not read yet`, `reading`, `read already`)

I intended to user `book_user` as many-to-many relation table, so I follow the name convention from [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> To define this relationship, three database tables are needed: **users**, **roles**, and **role_user**. The role_user table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the user_id and role_id columns.

I wrote code:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book');
    }
}
```

, and I can retrieve the books which related to the user by call `user->books()`.

**That works well**, but when I try to retrieve the state of the book which related to a user, I create model:

```
class BookUser extends Model
{
    //
}
```

When I use this Model, it claims:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myapp.book_users' doesn't exist
```

Conclusion:

- the name convention of a table which can be used as many-to-many is `<singular_noun>_<singular_noun>` (such as `book_user`).
- the name convention of table with multiple words which mapping to a Model is `<singular_noun>_<plural_noun>` (such as `book_users`).

I know I can set the table name manually which a model mappings to, but I just wonder:

Does that conflict is a **design flaw** or just I'm doing wrong in designing tables and models?

Comment: A user can have many books, so your relation should be `hasMany` from `user->book` change `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book');` to `return $this->hasMany('App\Book');` and also create reverseAssocation on `App\Book` model where you have `$this->belongsTo('App\User')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need define a model for pivot table,just add withPivot

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book')->withPivot('state');
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve book states from model pivot

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't need a model for pivot tables. You can define the inverse of the relationship. And if you want to store extra data in pivot table maybe you can check `withPivot` method. Or explain what are you trying to do.

But if you want to create a model, you need to specify your table name in your model manually. Because Laravel doesn't know if its a pivot table or normal table. It just tries to guess the table name by making it plural.